# I am getting some problem with int and str conversions in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need the following output:
Example output below (red text represents user inputs):

Please input the bean price: 5
Please input the bean price: 17
Please input the bean price: 23
Please input the bean price: max
The max bean prices is 23
Please input the bean price: min
The min bean price is 5
Please input the bean price: mean
The mean bean price is 15

My code is:

```
    li = []
    price = '0'
    val = True
    while val:
       price = int(input('Please input the bean price: ')
        if price!='max' and price!='min' and price!= 'mean':
           li.append(price)
        elif price=='max':
           max_value = li[0]
           for x in li:
              if int(x) > max_value:
                  max_value = int(x)
           print(f'The max bean price is {max_value}')
```

Can anyone provide with the solution please?

Comment: Don't cast your input to int immediately, do it when you append it to the list.

Comment: Should 'max', 'min' and 'mean' be variables if you are comparing them to price which is int? Enclosing them in ' ' makes them strings and essentially you're comparing user input to a string

Answer (score 0):

```
li = []
price = '0'
val = True
while val:
    price = input('Please input the bean price: ')
    if price!='max' and price!='min' and price!= 'mean':
        li.append(int(price))
    elif price=='max':
       max_value = li[0]
       for x in li:
          if x > max_value:
              max_value = x
       print(f'The max bean price is {max_value}')
    elif price=='min':
       min_value = li[0]
       for x in li:
          if x < min_value:
              min_value = x
       print(f'The min bean price is {min_value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt `min` and `max`. You should move the `int()` to the line where you add the number to the list: `li.append(int(price))`. Also, `.lower()` will help you to remove case sensetivity. The `if` statement will help to prevent the error.

Ex: if the user enters `max,min,mean` in the first statement, there is nothing in the list. So the `if...else` checks if list is not empty or `[]`.

```
li = []
price = '0'
val = True
li = []
price = '0'
val = True
while val:
    price = input('Please input the bean price: ')
    if price.lower()!='max' and price.lower()!='min' and price.lower()!= 'mean':
       li.append(int(price))
    elif price.lower()=='max':
       if li==[]:
          print("There is no item in the list.")
       else:
          print(f'The max bean price is {max(li)}')
    elif price.lower()=='min':
       if li==[]:
          print("There is no item in the list.")
       else:
          print(f'The min bean price is {min(li)}')
    elif price.lower()=='mean':
       if li==[]:
          print("There is no item in the list.")
       else:
          print(f'The mean bean price is {sum(li)/len(li)}')
```

Output:

```
Please input the bean price: 5
Please input the bean price: 17
Please input the bean price: 23
Please input the bean price: max
The max bean price is 23
Please input the bean price: min
The min bean price is 5
Please input the bean price: mean
The mean bean price is 15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can write this code `easier` and use `Python capabilities` instead of writing some things ourselves.

look at this

```
def funny():
    li=[]
    mxs = "The max bean price is"
    mns = "The min bean price is" 
    bns = "The mean bean price is"
    while True:
        price=input("Please input the bean price : ")
        if price.isdigit():
            li.append(int(price))
        elif price == "max":
            print(f"{mxs} {max(li)}")  
        elif price == "min":
            print(f"{mns} {min(li)}") 
        elif price == "mean":
            print(f"{bns} {sum(li)/len(li)}")
funny()
```